# Xcode user input: only first character shows up when inputting

Tags: xcode, input, io

When I am programming in Xcode (in C), and I am using the debugging console (brought forth with Cmd-R) to view the program and its output, and give it input, when I am entering input only the first character that I want to input shows up on the console. All the rest are invisible and non-selectable to me. Say I want to enter "20": all that shows up is "2". It still behaves as though I had entered all those characters (in the previous example, 20), so technically this bug (?) doesn't interfere with the actual software, but it's still annoying not to see all of the keystrokes that I had inputted previously. I just updated Xcode a day or two ago and installed Command Line Tools as well (though I doubt the latter is relevant). I believe the version number is 4.3 or so. Is anyone else having the same problem, and has anyone found a fix? Yes, I've tried restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
It looks like it's a XCode 4.5 bug:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/19701332?tstart=0#19701332?tstart=0

So, you can wait or install a previous version.